# Why does ng-model sometimes prepopulate and sometimes not?

Tags: angularjs

Why does a default value appear at all? I thought it was just supposed to bind an element to a scope property. I didn't realize it had anything to do with prepopulating. And why does the first text box prepopulate here, but not the second?

http://jsfiddle.net/ubwa4jgs/

js...

```
    angular.module('epfApp', [])
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $window) {

    $scope.questions = {
        '1': {
                'title': 'Why does a default value work here?',
                'type': 'text',
                'default': 'first question'
            } 
    };

    $scope.myChange = function() {
        console.log("a change just occurred");
    };

});
```

html...

```
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <label ng-repeat="question in questions">
        {{question.title}}
        <input type="text" ng-model="question.default" ng-change="change()" />
        <br />
    </label>
        <br />
    <label>
        Why does a default value NOT work here:
        <input type="text" ng-model="banana" ng-change="change()" />
        <br />
    </label>    

</div>
```

Edit: I appreciate the answers. I think it's the repeater that's throwing me off. Don't the ng-model values need to be unique for each element? I know it's wrong, but I feel like I need to have 'ng-model="question.default{{$index}}"' or something to force what's assigned to ng-model to be unique.

Edit 2:
I thought the job of the directives was to modify the DOM. After viewing the source, I see that the dom has been modified with various classes and comments added, but the ng-model values are still the same (question.default), that is, they're still relying on the ng-repeat directive to make them unique. So, ng-repeat appears to be an exception in that the unique (indexed) name of ng-model is implied but technically isn't ever physically reflected in the DOM?

updated http://jsfiddle.net/ubwa4jgs/

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="ng-scope">
    <!-- ngRepeat: question in questions --><label ng-repeat="question in questions" class="ng-scope ng-binding">Why does a default value work here?
        <input type="text" ng-model="question.default" ng-change="myChange()" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
        <br>
    </label><!-- end ngRepeat: question in questions --><label ng-repeat="question in questions" class="ng-scope ng-binding">Why does a default value work here too?
        <input type="text" ng-model="question.default" ng-change="myChange()" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
        <br>
    </label><!-- end ngRepeat: question in questions -->
    <br>
    <label>Why does a default value NOT work here:
        <input type="text" ng-model="banana" ng-change="myChange()" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
        <br>
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there is no `$scope.banana` value. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jLy1L6wg/).

```
angular.module('epfApp', [])
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $window) {

    $scope.questions = {
        '0': {
                'title': 'Why does a default value work here?',
                'type': 'text',
                'default': 'first question'
            } 
    };

    $scope.banana = "yellow";

});
```

"Why does a default value appear at all?" - [AngularJS two-way Data Binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_04).

Regarding your edit, you should have something like this:

```
<label ng-repeat="question in questions track by $index">
    {{questions[$index].title}}
    <input type="text" ng-model="questions[$index].value" ng-change="change()" /> {questions[$index].value}}
    <br />
</label>
```

See updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jLy1L6wg/4/) and note the first question is now '0'.

Comment: Thanks for the response. What I can't get my head around is the fact that, with ng-model, you can apparently assign it a non-unique value. For example, I'm used to seeing ng-model="user.name". Then in the controller something like "$scope.user = {name: 'Buddy'};" But the way it appears above is equivalent to assigning to ng-model the VALUE itself, e.g. "ng-model='Buddy'", which seems weird, because their could be multiple user names that are Buddy, meaning potentially redundant ng-models? Sorry, it's late. Hopefully I'll see the error of my ways tomorrow. Thanks again.

Comment: Rather than starting from scratch im really just trying to understand the proper assigning of ng-model, Maybe an easier way to ask is, what is the equivalent to banana for the first text box that? Doesn't ng-model have to be assigned to a unique variable name?

Comment: @user1893249 ng-model just needs an object property. In my answer the input model is **questions[$index].value**, in your question it is question.default so the value you see in the input is 'first question'. I've also just realised that question.default is actually OK and you don't need to use $index like I have shown because each question in the repeat is a separate object. You need to assign a **unique object property**.

Comment: @user1893249 The equivalent to banana for the first text box is $scope.questions[1].default.

Answer (score 1):

Hey this is very simple question.

It is becuase you have  `ng-model="question.default"` which is having value:-'first question'

But no value in banana model  ng-model="banana" in controller.

Here if updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rLc0pnjc/) for you.

Comment: Thanks. I think that what's assigned to ng-model is not unique is what's confusing me.  What is the equivalent to banana for the first text box?